# How to get users who clicked Share button on stream posts?

Tags: facebook-fql, share

There is nice system to retrieve users who clicked Like or Commented posts on the wall, but I can't find way to get users who clicked **Share**. (I prefer FQL). Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried?  What's your nice system for getting users who've clicked like and for those who've commented?

Comment: To get users who clicked Like or Commented, at first I get [Stream](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/stream/), then from it I get Likers ID by using [Like](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/like/) and Commenters ID by using [comment](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/comment/).